How to handle email/password, Facebook and Google authentication for app when our website uses Azure B2C?
We use Azure B2C on our ASP.NET website to authenticate our web users.
We are building our app in Flutter, and need the same user credentials to work across both the app and the website.
I have hit my head against a brick wall trying to implement the Azure B2C login web page inside the app, trying various WebView packages, and the flutter_custom_tabs package.
Webviews are not allowed by Google and Facebook for 3rd party auth (although the user agent can be hacked, but this doesn't seem like a good approach).
Chrome Custom Tabs blocks redirects back to the app's URI scheme. (msauth://), and the only hack to get around it is to build a custom page with a link that can be clicked on by the user to redirect them, which is a horrible UX.
From what I understand, it is best to take a native approach, build a email/password login form inside the app UI, and for Google/Facebook auth use native flutter packages for this.
Am I on the right track here or what would be the best approach?

I managed to eventually resolve this.
The only package I could ever get working properly with Chrome Custom Tabs that could handle the redirect back to my app is the Flutter AppAuth Plugin.
Using a WebView is not recommended due to security risks and can actually get your app rejected from Google Play/App Store submission. Most social login providers don't even allow you to attempt authentication in a WebView. Using the user's default browser/Chrome Custom tabs is considered best practice
Debug Android Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.your.app">
<!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
     the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- Add a reference to a configuration for a self-signed-certificate from your website localhost -->
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">-->
</application>

Android Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.your.app">
   <application
        android:label="your_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

defaultConfig section in build.gradle
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.your.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName                        
        manifestPlaceholders += ['appAuthRedirectScheme': 'yourscheme']
    }    

Note : Replace 'yourscheme' with your app redirect uri scheme protocol.
So if its yourscheme://1234, just place 'yourscheme' in the config.
network_security_config.xml (referenced by the debug Android manifest)
This points to a localhost.pem certificate in your app->src->main->res->raw folder, that is required when doing https calls from an emulator.
To generate a localhost.pem certificate, use mkcert
Add these domains to the cert

"localhost"
"127.0.0.1"
"10.0.2.2" (Standard IP for the host machine of the emulator, don't change this)

network_security_config.xml
Place in app->src->main->res->xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Configuration that points to a self signed certificate from your website localhost, which bypasses any cert issues from accessing localhost via the emulator -->
<!-- Copy the localhost.pem certificate file from the website root, to the android/app/src/main/res/raw folder in this project  -->
<!-- After any config change, always do a 'flutter clean', followed by 'flutter pub get', then run the app -->
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
         <certificates src="@raw/localhost"/>-->
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain>10.0.2.2</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/localhost"/>-->
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Note 2 : I didn't end up needing the B2C recommended config of setting up the android host and redirect uri hash etc with the flutter app_auth plugin.
I hope this helps somebody, I bashed my head against many brick walls to figure this all out.
Good luck.
